# Dynamically assign type to List<T> and populate it with deserialized json

Tags: c#

I have many classes that I use to keep objects of specific types together and do some things on them, eg. "CarKeeper" or "EmployeeKeeper":

```
public class CarKeeper
{
    List<Car> Items;
}

public class EmployeeKeeper
{
    List<Employee> Items;
}
```

I then populate Items property with data from web api service:

```
public async Task Refresh()
{
    if (Items.Any())
    {
        Items.Clear();
    }

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + "GetEmployees?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&page=1";

        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url)))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var userJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee[]>(userJsonString).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data gets properly deserialized and all works good. As creating another class like that (e.g. "DocumentKeeper") means copying a lot of code from any other "..Keeper" classes (they share 90% of code), I want to build single "Keeper" class to handle all objects.

The problem is that I need to somehow tell "Keeper" class what type it keeps, because it sometimes has to keep `List<Employee>` and sometimes list of other types. I thought about passing the type in "Keeper"'s contstructor and.. and I'm lost what to do with it later :) I also tried to make all lists List and it kinda works, but it's far from perfect.

How can I get my code working?

```
public class Keeper
{
    List<T> Items;

    public Keeper(Type T)
    {
        //make Items a list of int if int is passed as T
    }

    public async Task Refresh()
    {
        if (Items.Any())
        {
            Items.Clear();
        }

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string url = Secrets.ApiAddress + "GetItems?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&page=1";
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url)))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var userJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    //how to put the passed type to DeserializeObject<>?
                    Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(userJsonString).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass the type as a generic type, not as a `Type` object:

```
public abstract class KeeperBase<T>
{
    List<T> Items;

    public Keeper() { }

    protected abstract string GetRefreshApi { get; }
    public async Task Refresh()
    {
        if (Items.Any())
        {
            Items.Clear();
        }

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(GetRefreshApi)))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var userJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    //how to put the passed type to DeserializeObject<>?
                    Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(userJsonString).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public class CarKeeper : KeeperBase<Car>
{
    protected override string GetRefreshApi => Secrets.ApiAddress + "GetCars?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&page=1";
}
public class EmployeeKeeper : KeeperBase<Employee>
{
    protected override string GetRefreshApi => Secrets.ApiAddress + "GetEmployees?token=" + Secrets.TenantToken + "&page=1";
}
```

And, you can use them like this:

```
var carKeeper = new CarKeeper();
await carKeeper.Refresh();
foreach(var car in carKeeper.Items)
{
    // ...
}
```